# Laravel blade: Access method inside User model for authorized user

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Authorized user info can be accessed in blades using `auth()->user()->info..` , also other users info by `App\User::where('id' , someid)` , but how to call methods inside User Model for authorized user?

What i tried:

```
App\User::where('id' , auth()->user()->id)->MyMethod(another-user-instance); //Error: undefined method
App\User::MyMethod(another-user-instance): //Error: Wrong call, Its not static method!
App\User->MyMethod(another-user-instance): //Error: What? Unexpected ->
```

I have a `Post` model that is connected to `User` model using `belongsTo`, I can easily access my method in `User` by `$AnyPostInstance->BelongToUser->MyMethod(another-user-instance)` , but i don't know how to handle it for authorized user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, calling the following is redundant:

```
App\User::where('id' , auth()->user()->id)
```

You're accessing the existing `User`, via `auth()->user()` to get its `id` and query for the exact same `User`. Don't do that.

Secondly, you need to use `->first()` if you're calling `App\User`:

```
$user = App\User::first()->myMethod();
```

If you don't call `->first()`, then you're accessing the `Builder` class, which doesn't have a `myMethod()` function.

So, ways to access:

```
auth()->user()->myMethod();
// This will access the currently logged in User

App\User::first()->myMethod(); 
// This will get the first User from the database

App\User::where("id", "=", $someUserId)->first()->myMethod(); 
// This will return a specific user matching `$someUserId`
```

Comment: but `App\User::first()` returns first user in user table, not authorized user. also `auth()->user()->myMethod();` returns undefined myMethod(). I have never been able to use `auth()->user()` as `User` model. I'll try your last code. tnx.

Comment: That's bizarre. `auth()->user()` should return an instance of your `User`. Are you actually logged in? Cause `auth()->user()` will return `null` if you're not, and you can't call `myMethod()` on `null`. If possible, please call `dd(auth()->user())` and add that to your question for reference. Also, post your `User` model; might be helpful to see what `myMethod()` is.

Comment: Its working now. I had changed some authorization files before. tnx for your info.

Comment: I was wondering if that's what it was. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```php
App\User::where('id' , auth()->user()->id)->first()->MyMethod(another-user-instance);
```

The line above can be replaced with this one:

```php
auth()->user()->myMethod(another-user-instance);
```

Hope it helps.